# Is there a way to make YouTube videos tiny when you embed them?

Tags: youtube-api

If you look [here](http://dateequalsnull.com) you will see some YouTube videos. I set the zoom on them to .9. I would like to have the zoom be around .3 but many YouTube videos will not play when the zoom is that small. Is there any way to achieve the effect and still have the video play?

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube player has a minimum embed size of 200px by 200px.  You can read the YouTube api blog for more details.
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/minimum-embeds-200px-x-200px.html